# gio mount on localhost gives "permission denied"

Tags: mount, gnome, nfs

I am trying to setup a local NFS server and mount it as well locally for file-manager testing purposes.

Mounting the mointpoint with `mount` works fine:

```
sudo mount 127.0.0.1:/home/schwinn/software/thunar_test /mnt/NFS_Test
```

I can go to `/mnt/NFS_Test`, modify files, etc.

Though mounting it with `gio mount` gives me "permission denied":

> Possibly this computer is not permitted or a privileged port is expected.

```
$ gio mount nfs://127.0.0.1:/home/schwinn/software/thunar_test
gio: nfs://127.0.0.1:0/home/schwinn/software/thunar_test:
Erlaubnis verwehrt: Möglicherweise ist dieser Rechner nicht zugelassen oder ein privilegierter Port wird erwartet
```

My `/etc/exports` has only a single line:

```
/home/schwinn/software/thunar_test 127.0.0.1(rw,sync,root_squash,subtree_check)
```

I as well tried with `*` and other attributes, though no luck so far.

I did `sudo umount /mnt/NFS_Test` before testing, restarted the service with `sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart`.

Any idea on how to further debug this would be welcome!

Comment: Please run `LC_ALL=C gio mount ...` to get an error message in English.

Comment: LC_ALL=C works for 'gio --help', but for unknown reason not for this error message :/